# How do i make a video fully take up the screen width html?

Tags: html, css

So, I was trying to make a video take up the whole size of the screen but have failed multiple times. The best try to solve it was having the following code:

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted>
    <source src="highway-loop.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

but then, also there is a little border and it's not full screen like this
https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mz2UVuG
Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: Try setting `min-height: 100vh;` and `min-width: 100vw;`. Apart that no need to give `z-index: -1` to `video` just increase `z-index` of all other elements.

Comment: [link](https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mAibuGl) this is what happens if i do that
and yes i can do that but i thought this would better

Comment: if that the case let me see what can be done.

Comment: ok i apreciate it

Comment: That happens because the video's size ratio doesn't match to the screen's size ratio

Comment: what aspect ratio do i set it to then?

Comment: make the video to match screen's video

Comment: yes but what and some one else did the same thing with the same video but i probably took a different approach to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay="" loop="" muted>
    <source src="https://i.imgur.com/9f6mEiR.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

First you have z-index:-1 (which makes ur video go behind the screen/element) I changed it to z-index:1.

Click "Run this code" button to see that it works now. It also take full width and height of the div it is inside by default. Since in this current example nothing is stoping it, it does goes full size. Click "Full page" to confirm.

Thirdly the https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mz2UVuG looks like the borders are from the video itself and not from html/css.

Comment: the borders are not from the video the z index is cuz i wanted it to be that way

Comment: well than u should paste more HTML and CSS so we can see which element has borders or background.

Comment: html -> [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/qejulohoqi.xml)
css -> [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/epalicesor.css)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/be8n27tr/1/ so what is the problem? Full screen here https://jsfiddle.net/be8n27tr/1/show

Comment: [link](https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mPXWaey) it still does work how can i send the video? i am soory i am new

Comment: Seriously. 1) you need to learn english. 2) you need to learn basics of HTML & CSS.

Your video tag path is `<source src="highway-loop.mp4" type="video/mp4" />` you need to change it to full path (with https://example.com = `<source src="https://example.com/videos/highway-loop.mp4" type="video/mp4" />`) I used video from Imgur in my example: `<source src="https://i.imgur.com/9f6mEiR.mp4" type="video/mp4" />`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajhpbsye/show it does take full width

Comment: i am talking about this [link](https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mXYdeVz) and the reason i had z-index: -1; is there is some text i want to display above it and i have finished about 5 hours of html and css tutorial i agree i might be bad but doint discourage me man

Answer (score 0):

Use

```css
video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

because the `max-height` doesn't allow the width to increase.

Comment: same problem it becomes like this and takes up more space  [link](https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mAibuGl)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem 2 Months ago. But i **figured** it out :D

**Index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
```

...

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="video">
    <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

...

**Style.css**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #333333;
  }

  #video {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
```

I hope this might help you :D

Comment: thats not what i want it to be [link](https://nothing-to-see-he.re/57mCpjAMo)

Comment: then you could change something in the body section. like margin and padding. (or what you had before)

Comment: i dont this there is any margin or padding although here is the full code if there is something i missed
html -> [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/zofovojowa.xml)
css -> [link](https://paste.pythondiscord.com/apaxixebom.css)

Answer (score 0):

**Wrap your video in a container. And do something like this.**

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: coral;
}

video {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <video autoplay="" loop="" muted>
    <source src="https://i.imgur.com/9f6mEiR.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: but i dont want those bars i want the video itself to take up the whole screen

Comment: then make your video bigger! This is not a `css` issue your video's ratio is small.

Comment: the video worked on a different website its the same video